# Prove $f[A] \subseteq f[B] \Rightarrow A ⊆ B$, given f is injective.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I have constructed a proof for the above question, but do not know where I must use the hypothesis of injectivity:

(Note: Let $X,Y$ be sets with $A,B ⊆ X$ and $f:X \to Y $.)

Let $y∈f[A]$; then, there exists $a∈A$ s.t. $f(a) = y$. Since $f[A]⊆ f[B]$, then, we also have $y∈f[B]$ and so, $f(a)∈ f[B]$. We conclude $a∈B$. Thus, $a∈A  \Rightarrow a∈B$, so $A⊆B$.

Comment: You should write the question properly. What's $f,A,B$?

Comment: How do you conclude that $a\in B$? That's where you should use injectivity

Comment: The proof must be wrong as written since you never use the assumption of injectivity.  That being said, you only need one sentence to fix this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $x\in A$. Then $y=f(x)\in f(A)$ and because $f(A)\subseteq f(B)$ we have that $y\in f(B)$. So there exists $w$ in $B$ such that $f(w)=y=f(x)$. But $f$ is injective, whence $w=x$ and $x\in B$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt:

Assume $B \subset A$ ($B$ proper subset of $A$).
($A$ \ $B \not = \emptyset$)

There exists an $a \in A$ \ $B.$

$f(a) \in f(A$ \ $B) \subset f(A)$, i.e.

$f(a) \in f(A)$;

since $f$ is injective: $f(a) \not \in f(B)$,

contradicts the assumption $f(A)\subset f(B).$